# Triangular inequality of complex numbers

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis

Let $0<a, b<1$ such that $a+b=1$. If $u,v \in\mathbb{C}$, with $u\neq v$, and $|u|=1=|v|$, then
$|au+vb|<1$.

I have tried to prove it absurd but I do not reach a contradiction.
Let $z:=x+iy$ and $w:=c+id$ such that
$|a(x+iy)+b(c+id)|=1$

$\iff$ $\sqrt{(ax+bc)^2+(ay+bd)^2}=1$

$\iff$ $(ax+bc)^2+(ay+bd)^2=1$...

I finally have to

$xc+yd=1$,

but I don't see the contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't true.  Let $u=2,v=2i$.  And $a,b=1/2$.  Then we get $|au+bv|=|1+i|=\sqrt2\gt1$.  In fact, we can take $u=r,v=ri$, and get $|au+bv|=\sqrt2r/2$.

On the other hand after your edit it's true, because when the angle between $z$ and $w$ is greater than zero, $|z+w|\lt |z|+|w|$.  So we get $|au+bv|\lt a|u|+b|v|=a+b=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the square of the modulus
$$
|au+bv|^2=(au+bv)(a\bar{u}+b\bar{v})=a^2+b^2+ab(u\bar{v}+\bar{u}v)
$$
Since $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab=1-2ab$, the inequality to prove becomes
$$
1+ab(u\bar{v}+\bar{u}v-2)<1
$$
Since $ab>0$, this becomes
$$
u\bar{v}+\bar{u}v<2
$$
(note that this makes sense because the left-hand side is real).

Let $w=uv^{-1}=u\bar{v}$. Then also $|w|=1$ and the inequality is $w+\bar{w}<2$, which amounts to saying that
$$
\operatorname{Re}(w)<1
$$
which is true because $w\ne1$ by assumption.